# Argument 1 passed to App\Http\Controllers\Auth\LoginController::authenticated()

Tags: php, laravel, validation, laravel-5

Help me understand and solve such errors.

ERROR :

> Symfony \ Component \ Debug \ Exception \ FatalThrowableError (E_RECOVERABLE_ERROR)
>   Type error: Argument 1 passed to App\Http\Controllers\Auth\LoginController::authenticated() must be an instance of App\Http\Controllers\Auth\Request, instance of Illuminate\Http\Request given, called in C:\proj\easywash\vendor\laravel\framework\src\Illuminate\Foundation\Auth\AuthenticatesUsers.php on line 104

---

Login Controller :

```
    <?php

namespace App\Http\Controllers\Auth;

use App\Http\Controllers\Controller;
use Illuminate\Foundation\Auth\AuthenticatesUsers;
use Illuminate\Http\Request;
use App\Http\Requests;
use Auth;
class LoginController extends Controller
{
    /*
    |--------------------------------------------------------------------------
    | Login Controller
    |--------------------------------------------------------------------------
    |
    | This controller handles authenticating users for the application and
    | redirecting them to your home screen. The controller uses a trait
    | to conveniently provide its functionality to your applications.
    |
    */

    use AuthenticatesUsers;

    /**
     * Where to redirect users after login.
     *
     * @var string
     */
    protected $redirectTo = '/home';

    /**
     * Create a new controller instance.
     *
     * @return void
     */
    public function __construct()
    {
        $this->middleware('guest', ['except'=> ['logout','userLogout']]);
    }

    public function authenticated(Request $request, $user)
        {
            if (!$user->verified) {
                auth()->logout();
                return back()->with('warning', 'You need to confirm your account. We have sent you an activation code, please check your email.');
            }
            return redirect()->intended($this->redirectPath());
        }

    public function userLogout()
    {
        Auth::guard('web')->logout();
        return redirect('/home');
    }
}
```

Register Controller :

```
<?php

namespace App\Http\Controllers\Auth;
use App\User;
use App\Mail\VerifyMail;
use App\Http\Controllers\Controller;
use Illuminate\Support\Facades\Validator;
use Illuminate\Foundation\Auth\RegistersUsers;
use App\VerifyUser;
use Auth;
use DB;
use Mail;
use Illuminate\Http\Request;

class RegisterController extends Controller
{
    /*
    |--------------------------------------------------------------------------
    | Register Controller
    |--------------------------------------------------------------------------
    |
    | This controller handles the registration of new users as well as their
    | validation and creation. By default this controller uses a trait to
    | provide this functionality without requiring any additional code.
    |
    */

    use RegistersUsers;

    /**
     * Where to redirect users after registration.
     *
     * @var string
     */
    protected $redirectTo = '/home';

    /**
     * Create a new controller instance.
     *
     * @return void
     */
    public function __construct()
    {
        $this->middleware('guest');
    }

    /**
     * Get a validator for an incoming registration request.
     *
     * @param  array  $data
     * @return \Illuminate\Contracts\Validation\Validator
     */
    protected function validator(array $data)
    {
        return Validator::make($data, [
            'name' => 'required|string|max:255',
            'email' => 'required|string|email|max:255|unique:users',
            'password' => 'required|string|min:6|confirmed',

        ]);
    }

    /**
     * Create a new user instance after a valid registration.
     *
     * @param  array  $data
     * @return \App\User
     */
    protected function create(array $data)
    {
               $user = User::create([
                    'name' => $data['name'],
                    'email' => $data['email'],
                    'password' => bcrypt($data['password']),
                ]);

                $verifyUser = VerifyUser::create([
                    'user_id' => $user->id,
                    'token' => str_random(40)
                ]);

                Mail::to($user->email)->send(new VerifyMail($user));

                return $user;


    }

    public function verifyUser($token)
    {
        $verifyUser = VerifyUser::where('token', $token)->first();
        if(isset($verifyUser) ){
            $user = $verifyUser->user;
            if(!$user->verified) {
                $verifyUser->user->verified = 1;
                $verifyUser->user->save();
                $status = "Your e-mail is verified. You can now login.";
            }else{
                $status = "Your e-mail is already verified. You can now login.";
            }
        }else{
            return redirect('/login')->with('warning', "Sorry your email cannot be identified.");
        }

        return redirect('/login')->with('status', $status);
    }
    protected function registered(Request $request, $user)
    {
        $this->guard()->logout();
        return redirect('/login')->with('status', 'We sent you an activation code. Check your email and click on the link to verify.');
    }


   }
```

Comment: It expects `App\Http\Controllers\Auth\Request` instead of `Illuminate\Http\Request`, so use it.

Comment: There is little to comment here, your error actually already says what to do.

Answer (score 6):

I also had the same [problem](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/56116488/instance-have-been-given-still-detect-other-instance-in-controllers/) as you and I solved that with this [answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/56116932/6255049).

---

**ANSWER**

Change your `use` statement at LoginController:

```
use Illuminate\Http\Request;
// And try to comment out the next line
// use App\Http\Requests;
```

You're overriding [this](https://github.com/laravel/framework/blob/d8a626c4f7c70e792de9225f0c41405b4533e9d7/src/Illuminate/Foundation/Auth/AuthenticatesUsers.php#L120) method from the `AuthenticatesUsers` trait, which receives a `Illuminate\Http\Request`, not a `App\Http\Controllers\Auth\Request`

Answer (score 0):

directory -> app -> controller -> Auth -> RegisterController

```
protected function create(array $data)
{
    return User::create([
        'name' => $data['name'],
        'email' => $data['email'],
        'password' => Hash::make($data['password']),
    ]);`enter code here`
}
```

control+x code and control+v on User Model

so  use terminal php artisan route:list