# Instance have been given, still detect other instance in controllers

Tags: php, laravel

Im trying to get client IP through controller named LoginController but the error still there.

> Argument 1 passed to App\Http\Controllers\Auth\LoginController::authenticated() must be an instance of App\Http\Controllers\Auth\Request, instance of Illuminate\Http\Request given

I've follow this [SO question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/45191753/argument-1-passed-must-be-an-instance-of-app-request-instance-of-illuminate-htt) but still get the same error.

---

LoginController.php

```
namespace App\Http\Controllers\Auth;

use App\Http\Controllers\Controller;
use App\Http\Controllers\Auth\Request;

class LoginController extends Controller
{
     /**
     * The user has been authenticated.
     *
     * @param  App\Http\Controllers\Auth\Request $request
     * @param  mixed  $user
     * 
     * @return mixed
     */
    protected function authenticated(Request $request, $user)
    {
        $user->update([
            'last_login_at' => Carbon::now()->toDateTimeString(),
            'last_login_ip' => $request->getClientIp()
        ]);

        if($user->isAdmin === 1) {
            return redirect()->intended('admin');
        }
    }
}
```

---

**EDITED**

So, I just found out about AuthenticatesUsers.php which is a trait(?) and found this code. Should I edit this code or not?

```
/**
 * The user has been authenticated.
 *
 * @param  \Illuminate\Http\Request  $request
 * @param  mixed  $user
 * @return mixed
 */
 protected function authenticated(Request $request, $user)
 {
    //
 }
```

Comment: It is not clear what you are asking. How have you followed the answer given in the link you provide?

Comment: @JonGuiton I had change the `use App\Http\Controllers\Auth\Request` to `use Illuminate\Http\Request` but still getting the same error so I thought the solution is not working. I must have been missed something. Anyway, the question had been answered with the same answer as that SO answer. :shakehead: My bad.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Change your `use` statement:

```
use Illuminate\Http\Request;
// Instead of
use App\Http\Controllers\Auth\Request;
```

You're overriding [this method](https://github.com/laravel/framework/blob/d8a626c4f7c70e792de9225f0c41405b4533e9d7/src/Illuminate/Foundation/Auth/AuthenticatesUsers.php#L120) from the `AuthenticatesUsers` trait, which receives a `Illuminate\Http\Request`, not a `App\Http\Controllers\Auth\Request`

Comment: Ahh.., but the error said `must be an instance of App\Http\Controllers\Auth\Request`. I thought the function needs to use that request. Thanks for you help!

Comment: @Qrazier It said that because you defined the method with a parameter of type `App\Http\Controllers\Auth\Request` but Laravel still passes a `Illuminate\Http\Request` to it.